# Jenkins returns "null" for System.getenv("BUILD_URL") when called in TestNG block '@BeforeClass', Why?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

If I call `getBuildURL()` inside some @Test, I get proper Jenkins Job URL but if I make call to same method in `@BeforeClass` I get `null` why?

```
/**
 * Get Current Jenkins BuildURL
 * @return
 */
private String getBuildURL() {
    String buildURL = System.getenv("BUILD_URL");
    if (buildURL == null) {
        return "#";
    } else {
        return buildURL + "console";
    }
}
```